# Filter a table to keep only non-redundant groups

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis, mathematical-optimization, hierarchical-clustering

I've been performing phylogenetic analysis in R for a while, employing libraries like ape, phangorn and phytools.

While solving a problem, I've come to a presence/absence data.frame that specifies if genes of interest belong (or don't) to a certain group.

An example of this would be:

```
             gene11    gene25  gene33  gene54  gene55 gene65 gene73   gene88
group_1         1        1        0      0       0     0      0       0      
group_2         1        1        1      0       0     0      0       0      
group_3         1        0        1      0       0     0      0       0      
group_4         0        1        1      0       0     0      0       0      
group_5         0        0        0      1       1     0      0       0      
group_6         0        0        0      1       0     0      0       0      
group_7         0        0        0      0       1     0      0       0      
group_8         0        0        0      0       0     1      1       1      
group_9         0        0        0      0       0     1      1       0      
group_10        0        0        0      0       0     1      0       1      
group_11        0        0        0      0       0     0      1       1
```

As expected when dealing with groups of biological entities, there many ways in which this entities relate: genes 11, 25 and 33 form a group, and also their relationships could be described smaller groups, depicting pairwise relationships.

**So here is the important thing**: **group_2**, **group_5** and **group_8** are the biologically relevant groups of genes, and they **aren't known beforehand as the relevant groups**. 
The other, smaller groups, arise as a consequence of the relationship shown in these relevant groups: group_1 relates gene11 and gene25, but is a group that is nested in the *broader* (and relevant) group_2. 
The same applies in the other cases: group_8 depicts a relationship between gene65, gene73 and gene88; the other groups concerning these genes (group_9, group_10 and group_11) are only subgroups depicting the pairwise relationships existing among the genes that are part of the broader group group_8.

**What is known beforehand** is that genes form clusters of disjoint groups, each cluster being composed of other (progressively smaller) clusters. I'm interested in capturing the biggest-disjoint groups.

**A clear definition of the problem** was done by another user (@Shree):

> Find minimum number of groups such that all other groups are a
>   sub-group of at least one of those groups. Also a group has to have at
>   least 2 genes i.e. two 1s in a row. Also assuming, 1,01,0 is a
>   subgroup of `1,1,1,0` but `0,1,1,1` is not a subgroup of `1,1,1,0`.

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Is this known beforehand - *"group_2, group_5 and group_8 are the biologically relevant groups of genes"*?

Comment: Dear @Shree, no, these groups aren't known beforehand: it is the ultimate goal of the analysis to identify automatically these relevant groups. I will add this fact to the post.

Comment: I dont' want to enter in details related to phylogenetics, but I am 100% sure that this kind of behaviour is not going to happen: genes that belong to a group form a cluster only in that group, and won't appear in other groups (i.e. the groups of interest are disjoint). What I know beforehand is that genes form clusters of disjoint groups, each cluster being composed of other (progressively smaller) clusters. I'm interested in capturing the biggest-disjoint groups. Hope that makes sense to you @Shree . Thanks again!

Comment: Can any relevant group have multiple sets of consecutive `1`s example: `c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)` or can I assume any relevant group to have only one set of consecutive `1`s like shown in both examples in the question?

Comment: Groups are not necessarily composed of genes that appear as consecutive 1's: a group could perfectly be represented in a row like c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0).

Comment: Okay, this certainly falls under optimization/clustering problems. I have already added those tags to the post so hopefully it'll get seen by relevant people. I'll try and provide an optimization solution. Does the following make sense - *Find minimum number of groups such that all other groups are a sub-group of at least one of those groups. Also a group has to have at least 2 genes i.e. two `1`s in a row. Also assuming, `1,01,0` is a subgroup of `1,1,1,0` but `0,1,1,1` is not a subgroup of `1,1,1,0`*.

Comment: Great @Shree! Thank you so much for expressing the problem in such a clear way! Also for suggesting that classification for the problem, I think that is exactly the case. Should I add your last definition to the post?

Comment: Done! Thank you so much @Shree for your interest and your suggestions.

Comment: Great, I'll update the definition a bit later. What are the dimensions of your actual dataframe?

Comment: It depends on the tree being analyzed. I perform the analysis on ~30.000 phylogenetic trees. Each phylogenetic tree has its own set of genes, the number of genes in the data.frame ranging from 2 (trivial) to ~100 (worst case).

Comment: okay, 100 columns. And how many rows, 30,000? I have no background in genetics so you'd have describe it like a math problem for me.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that! Worst case scenario, with 100 columns and ~400 columns (for a single file being analyzed; my original idea was to define a function and to perform a loop over the ~30.000 files to be analyzed). Hope now the scenario is a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you mean 400 rows or 400 columns?

Comment: If you have n columns, the number of rows is, in the worst case, ~4n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using mixed integer programming approach. I am using `ompr` for mathematical modeling and `glpk` (free open source) as solver. Modeling logic is provided as comments in code.

I think the problem can be mathematically described as follows -

> Filter dataframe to minimize number of rows such that sum of all columns is 1. Selected rows are called primary groups and every other row should be a subgroup of a primary group. A column (gene) can belong to only one primary group. Any unselected row is a subgroup of a primary group when `subgroup <= primary group` at all positions (columns). Therefore, `(0,0,1,1)` is subgroup of `(0,1,1,1)` but `(1,0,1,1)` is not a subgroup of `(0,1,1,1)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

gene_mat <- as.matrix(df)
nr <- nrow(gene_mat)
nc <- ncol(gene_mat)

model <- MIPModel() %>% 
  # binary variable x[i] is 1 if row i is selected else 0
  add_variable(x[i], i = 1:nr, type = "binary") %>% 
  # minimize total rows selected
  set_objective(sum_expr(x[i], i = 1:nr), "min") %>% 
  # sum of columns of selected rows must be = 1
  add_constraint(sum_expr(gene_mat[i,j]*x[i], i = 1:nr) == 1, j = 1:nc) %>% 
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))

# get rows selected
group_rows <- model %>% 
  get_solution(x[i]) %>% 
  filter(value > 0) %>% 
  pull(i) %>% 
  print()

result <- df[group_rows, ]

        gene11 gene25 gene33 gene54 gene55 gene65 gene73 gene88
group_2      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
group_5      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
group_8      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1
```

**Important Note -**

The above formulation does not address `subgroup <= primary group` but instead relies on the fact that OP mentions *"What is known beforehand is that genes form clusters of disjoint groups"*. This means cases like shown below do not exist in data since rows 1,3,4 do not form disjoint groups i.e column 3 would belong to 2 primary groups which is not allowed.

```
1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 <- this row is not a subgroup of any row
0 0 1 1 1
```

Anyways, here's code to do a safety check to make sure all unselected rows are subgroup of only one primary group -

```
test <- lapply(group_rows, function(x) {
  sweep(df, 2, as.numeric(df[x, ]), "<=") %>% 
    {which(rowSums(.) == ncol(df))}
})

# all is okay if below returns TRUE
length(Reduce(intersect, test)) == 0
```

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(
  gene11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,0L, 0L), 
  gene25 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  gene33 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  gene54 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  gene55 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  gene65 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
  gene73 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
  gene88 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c("group_1", "group_2", "group_3", "group_4", 
                "group_5", "group_6", "group_7", "group_8",
                "group_9", "group_10", "group_11")
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the reply Shree. Actually I should have been more precise when formulating the problem: I need a general solution, because this is not the only set of genes that I will be analyzing. The total set involves thousands of groups like these, so it is not possible to do this kind of filtering.

Comment: @mauricio.langleib I have no idea what the following means: *"I'm only interested in the broadest group relating them, group_7"*. If you add 2-3 examples to your post so then I will understand what generalization is needed.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I have edited the post and added another example with an explanation. Hope now the problem is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @mauricio.langleib See the updated answer. Try it with a few of your datasets and let me know how it works out.

Comment: Great! I'm gonna try the code as soon as I can and I'll let you know how it works. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @mauricio.langleib As long as my problem definition (yellow highlighted text) is correct, this code will work.

Comment: Dear @Shree, indeed your code solve my problem! Thank you so much for your interest in solving it. I have selected your response as correct. If there is another way to give you credit for your participation please let me now (I'm new in StackOverflow). Cheers!

Comment: @mauricio.langleib You can also upvote the answer. See [How to upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). That's all the credit I need. I enjoy working on optimization problems so happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option where we `split` the data into chunks of data columns with a grouping index created with `rep` (here, the 1 and 2 corresponds to the first 3 and next 2 columns), then loop through the `list`, use `filter_all` to extract the rows with all 1s and `mutate` by replacing the NA to 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
split.default(df, rep(1:2, c(3, 2))) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
                  filter_at(-1, all_vars(.==1))) %>% 
        mutate_all(replace_na, 0) %>%
        column_to_rownames('rn')
#.       gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5
#group_1     1     1     1     0     0
#group_7     0     0     0     1     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(gene1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gene2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gene3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), gene4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), gene5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", 
"gene5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("group_1", "group_2", 
"group_3", "group_4", "group_5", "group_6", "group_7"))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun! Thanks for the answer! This solution perfectly works in this specific case, but unfortunately what I am needing is a more general solution. I have edited the post in order to explain what I mean by this. Sorry for not being clear, and thanks again for your interest in helping me!

Comment: @mauricio.langleib. It is a general solution.  Only thing to change is how you want to group the columnss, which is not clear to me

Comment: Dear @akrun, it is not general in the sense that I dont now a priori which rows I want to conserve, because I don't know a priori which groups are formed between the genes. I need collapse the redundancy among rows automatically.